# arc length enclosed by $r=1+\cos\theta$ and $r=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find the arc length enclosed by $r=1+\cos\theta$ and $r=1$

What i try:

[image]

Solving $r=1+\cos\theta$ and $r=1$.

We get $\displaystyle 1+\cos\theta=1\Longrightarrow \theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Using arc length formula

$$\int^{b}_{a}\sqrt{r^2+\bigg(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\bigg)^2}d\theta$$

I did not understand How can i find upper limit and lower limit . Because i am getting only one limit.

Help me please.

Comment: arclength means length, right? why the "enclosed" then? That would mean the red branch located between $\theta=\pi/2$ and $\theta=3\pi/2$?

Comment: What means upper limit here?

Comment: Thanks pluton. Can i take theta from $\displaystyle -\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}.$

Comment: Which one of these - the red colored sinusoidal parts or half circle (length $\pi $) is being considered enclosed? Or is it sum of the two aforementioned arcs?

Comment: if you choose $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$, you parameterize the outer red branch believe.

Answer (score 2):

$\cos\theta=0$ has 2 solutions for $0< \theta<2\pi$,
Namely $\theta= \pi/2, 3 \pi/2$

Comment: Thanks sven 456. Can i take theta from $\displaystyle -\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}.$

Comment: Please click on the edit option and review the edits I made to your [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) formatting so that you can do the same in the future

Answer (score 1):

From the information given (which lacks clarity) you want to compute the following integral $$\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} \sqrt{r^2+r'^2}\mathrm{d}\theta$$ where $r(\theta)=1+\cos\theta$ and $r'(\theta)=-\sin\theta$. The above integral thus reduces to $$\sqrt{2}\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} \sqrt{1+\cos\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta$$